# Command prompt FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /B') fails for first result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using a batch file to rename all files in a folder into a numbered list. The code I use is as follow:

```
set /a Index=1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
echo %%f
echo !Index!
rename "%%f" "!Index!.*"
set /a Index+=1
pause
)
```

The result of the batch file is

```
G:\Directory A> (
echo
03.jpg
echo 1
rename "
03.jpg" "1.*"
set /a Index+=1
pause
)

03.jpg
1
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .

G:\Directory A> (
echo 04.jpg
echo 1
rename "04.jpg" "1.*"
set /a Index+=1
pause
)
04.jpg
1
```

The first result ALWAYS contains a line break at the beginning of the file name, which causes the RENAME command to fail. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

---

#### UPDATE

There is the folloging auto-run code set up in the Windows registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="@chcp 65001>nul & prompt $d$s$s$t$_$p$g & cls"
```

Comment: Are you sure, the line break is not part of the filename? Your code should work fine.

Comment: @Stephan Yeah, I'm pretty sure about it, since this happened with any folder I tested on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a bit with my batch file, I recognized that this is a problem with the Autorun option that I had set ages ago in Registry that look like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="@chcp 65001>nul & prompt $d$s$s$t$_$p$g & cls"
```

Apparently the CLS command caused the weird line break to happen. After removing the CLS part from Autorun, the batch file works as it is intended to.

Comment: This is an interesting finding! The `cls` command sends a form-feed character (code `0x0C`) to the console – this is what you are capturing at the beginning of the very first line of the `dir /B` output, because `for /F` runs that `dir /B` in a new `cmd.exe` instance, so the auto-run code becomes again executed, leaving behind said character. A possible work-around is to replace `dir /B` by `echo _^& dir /B` and to add the `for /F` option `skip=1`; this would even work without any of your auto-run code…

Answer (score 1):

The finding described in the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74488656) is very interesting albeit tremendously nasty!

The auto-run code contains the [`cls` command](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html), which sends a single form-feed character (<kbd>FF</kbd>, code`0x0C`) to the console that tells it to clear the screen (the character can be displayed by running `cls > con` in the console).

When executing `cls` within a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), the <kbd>FF</kbd> is captured: `for /F %F in ('cls') do @echo/%F` in the command prompt displays that character.

A `for /F` loop initiates a new [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance to execute the given command line; this is done by preceding `cmd /C` to the command line.

With auto-run commands set up, they become executed within the `for /F` loop (due to the unfortunate lack of the `/D` option, which would prevent them to run).

The auto-run command line from the question has got `cls` involved, so `for /F %F in ('rem') do @echo/%F` captures a <kbd>FF</kbd>, even though the actual command `rem` does not return anything.

---

There are methods to suppress the <kbd>FF</kbd> character (note that the following code examples are intended to be placed in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) rather than entered into the console):

1. Precede the desired command line by `echo/&` to append a line-break to a potential <kbd>FF</kbd> to have an extra line at the beginning and skip that line by `for /F`:

   ```cmd
   rem // Precede the desired command with `echo/` and skip the first line:
   for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('echo/^& dir /B') do echo "%%I"
   ```
2. Retrieve a <kbd>FF</kbd> first and define it as the `eol` (end of line) character for `for /F`, then again prefix the desired command line with `echo/&` just like before:

   ```cmd
   rem // Retrieve the form-feed character and ignore lines beginning with a form-feed:
   for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ('echo/^& cls') do set "_FF=%%F"

   rem // Precede the desired command with `echo/` and use form-feed as `eol` character:
   for /F "delims= eol=%_FF%" %%I in ('echo/^& dir /B') do echo "%%I"
   ```

---

A more complex way needs to be gone when the auto-run code may write several arbitrary lines (that may even be empty). For this the number of said lines needs to be determined in order to become able to skip that number of lines later:

```cmd
rem /* Determine the number of lines that the `AutoRun` code regurgitates, including empty ones;
rem    the command line actually executed by `for /F` implicitly using `cmd /C` is as follows:
rem    `chcp 437 > nul & echo/& cmd /C echo/| find /C /V ""`
rem    this first returns a line-break, to have potential `AutoRun` text separated from the rest;
rem    then another `AutoRun` text again with a terminal line-break is generated, but this time
rem    piped into `find /C /V ""` in order to count the number of lines;
rem    `chcp 437 > nul` is necessary to set the code page for the implicit `cmd.exe` instance,
rem    because `find` (just like `more`) may have issues with some particulay Unicode code pages
rem    (like 65001, which may be set by the `AutoRun` code): */
for /F %%C in ('chcp 437 ^> nul ^& echo/^& cmd /C echo/^| find /C /V ""') do set /A "SKIP=%%C" 2> nul
if %SKIP% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%SKIP%") else set "SKIP="

rem // Precede the desired command with `echo/` and skip as many lines as necessary:
for /F "%SKIP% delims=" %%I in ('echo/^& dir /B') do echo "%%I"
```